# How Can I View Applied Filters in Gimp

Tags: gimp, layers, filter

I would like to see the filters that are applied to a (text or image) layer in GIMP. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to give a little more detail. There isn't enough information here for anyone to understand exactly what it is you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: No.

When you apply a filter to a text layer in GIMP, you modify its pixels. You will notice that it actually changes it appearance in the layers dialog from a "this is Text"-style icon to the appearance of other layers, that is a small preview of their content.

In a very special case: kind of

If you are working on an image, and apply some filters to a text layer, then the undo journal dialog will show you those. Only by name, though, and you won't see the values you have used, as the journal only stores previous instances of the whole image, not individual layers or filters. This only helps with "what filters did I use just now" and won't be useful later.

Better support for this is expected to be available in GIMP 3.x and beyond.